# Add JSON or XML or CSV data to MySQL server

Tags: python, mysql, json, xml, csv

Is there any way of sending either JSON, XML, or CSV data to a local MySQL server?

I'm new to MySQL, and wasn't able to find anything online.

Either data type will work as I have code that can covert all of my data into whichever format I require, i.e. JSON, XML, and CSV.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

> **1).** I am going to give you answer for JSON `>>` **How to store JSON data in MySQL DB using python ?**

If your JSON format is following and you want to store associative in MySQL `database >> table` then you can follow the first example.

**Example: 1**

JSON format

```
{
 "first_key" : 10,
 "second_key" : 20
}
```

Python core script for JSON.

```
import MySQLdb

myjson = json.loads(jdata)

def dbconnect():
    try:
        db = MySQLdb.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            passwd='',
            db='myjson_db'
        )
    except Exception as e:
        sys.exit("Can't connect to database")
    return db

cursor = db.cursor()

sql = """INSERT INTO my_table (array_key, array_value) VALUES (%s, %s)"""

for array_key, array_value in myjson.items():
    cursor.execute(sql, (array_key, array_value))
```

If you want to store data in only one column then you can follow the second one as per follow.

**Example: 2**

```
import MySQLdb

myjson = json.loads(jdata)

def dbconnect():
    try:
        db = MySQLdb.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            passwd='',
            db='myjson_db'
        )
    except Exception as e:
        sys.exit("Can't connect to database")
    return db

cursor = db.cursor()

sql = """INSERT INTO my_table (json_column) VALUES (%s)"""

cursor.execute(sql, (myjson))
```

> **2).** Lets start with XML `>>` **How to store XML data in MySQL DB using
>   python ?**

XML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<first_key>10</first_key>
<second_key>20</second_key>
```

Next step is: please install: Python script for converts XML to JSON from [here](https://github.com/hay/xml2json) import and `import xml2json` in our python core script.

Python Core script for XML

```
import MySQLdb
import xml2json
import json

xml_data = json.loads(xml2json.xml2json(xmldata))

### data store functionality or logic is same as example 1 and example 2
def dbconnect():
    try:
        db = MySQLdb.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            passwd='',
            db='myxml_db'
        )
    except Exception as e:
        sys.exit("Can't connect to database")
    return db

cursor = db.cursor()

sql = """INSERT INTO my_table (xml_data) VALUES (%s)"""

cursor.execute(sql, (xml_data))
```

> **3).** Lets discuss for CSV `>>` **How to store CSV data in MySQL DB using
>   python ?**

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

csv_data = csv.reader(file('my_csv_file.csv'))

def dbconnect():
    try:
        db = MySQLdb.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            passwd='',
            db='mycsv_db'
        )
    except Exception as e:
        sys.exit("Can't connect to database")
    return db

for row in csv_data:

    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO my_csv_table(csv_first_column, \
          csv_first_column)' \
          'VALUES("%s", "%s")', 
          row)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of anyway of inserting JSON, XML or CSV into a MySQL database directly.

You can parse the data to a script which can insert it into a Database by using a module such as [MySQL-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5).

My python isn't great but hopefully this example should suffice.

```
#!usr/bin/python
# Import mySQL module to interact with database.
import MySQLdb
# Import json module to convert the JSON into a Python data structure.
import json

# Convert the JSON to a usable format.
data = json.loads(yourjson) 

# Connect to MySQL server.
db = mySQLdb.connect(host='yourhost',
                     user='youruser',
                     passwd='yourpassword',
                     db='yourschema')

# Create an object to handle SQL statements.
cur = db.cursor()

# Attempt to execute the SQL statement, if not revert any changes.
try:
  cur.execute('INSERT INTO table SET col1 = %s, col2 = %s', data.foo, data.bar)
  db.commit()
except:
  db.rollback()
```